# Django model with many-to-one or none relationship vs many-to-many through?

Tags: python, django, django-models, model

I'm trying to build a application that lets people view tweets posted by politicians, and I'm struggling with the right way to specify the relationship between a user on Twitter and a user offline. For example, one politicians may have two Twitter accounts, and those accounts may mention three other Twitter users who are not politicians. Right now, I have a User table that contains info from the Twitter API (e.g., number of followers, number of tweets) that would have the Twitter info from both the politicians' accounts and those s/he mentioned and a Legislator table that contains info about legislators (e.g., party, chamber).

- Users relate to Legislators on twitter_id
- Users can have 0 or 1 entries in the Legislator table
- Legislators can have 0, 1, or n entries in the Users table

How would I set that model up correctly for Django? How do I access both user and legislator information in a template? With the setup below, I can't access anything in the legislator table from user.legislator_set.

```
class User(models.Model):
  id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
  twitter_id = models.CharField(max_length=21, unique=True)
  twitter_name = models.CharField(max_length=55, unique=True)
  fullname = models.CharField(max_length=45)
  followers = models.IntegerField()
  following = models.IntegerField()
  favorites = models.IntegerField()
  tweets = models.IntegerField()
  timezone = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)

class Legislator(models.Model):
  id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=17, blank=True)
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True)
  chamber = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=True)
  state = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True)
  party = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True)
  twitter_id = models.ForeignKey(User, to_field = "twitter_id", related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_id")
  twitter = models.ForeignKey(User, to_field = "twitter_name", related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_name")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Users relate to Legislators on `twitter_id`"? If you have multiple `User` instances per `Legislator`, it would be impossible to get them all to match by `twitter_id`, unless all of the `User` instances involved have the same `twitter_id`. It seems to me you just need to add a `legislator = models.ForeignKey(Legislator, null=True)` field on your `User` model, and remove the `Legislator.twitter_id` and `Legislator.twitter` fields, but I might not be seeing your entire scenario.

Comment: By "Users relate to Legislators on `twitter_id`" I meant that twitter_id is how I match them up (that's what I'd join on if I weren't using Django and were just pulling from a MySQL db). What would `legislator = models.ForeignKey(Legislator, null=True)` use to relate the two tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libby. If I'm understanding your requirements, this seems like the simplest starting point -- a many-to-one relationship using a ForeignKey field. (This is basically the same thing as lanzz's suggestion.)

```
class User(models.Model):
  twitter_id = models.CharField(max_length=21, unique=True)
  twitter_name = models.CharField(max_length=55, unique=True)
  # ... other fields characterizing a Twitter account
  legislator = models.ForeignKey('Legislator', blank=True, null=True)

class Legislator(models.Model):
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=17, blank=True)
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True)
  # ... other fields characterizing a legislator
```

In your Python code, given a twitter account `u` and legislator `l`, you'd run `u.legislator = l` to associate a legislator with a twitter account. You could also express that as `l.user_set.add(u)`, which makes more sense to me given these models.

Similarly, you'd use `Legislator.user_set`to access the RelatedManager for twitter accounts. This is what you'd loop over in a template or do additional queries against when you want to work with the related model (any/all related twitter accounts) instead of the one you have (a legislator).

There are a few more usage examples [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/).

In the `ForeignKey` field, I set `blank=True, null=True` to make the relationship optional. Unless you specify otherwise in the field's options, Django will create and use a `legislator_id` column in the `User` table to manage the relationship.

Comment: Ah, ok. So I add the `legislator = models.ForeignKey('Legislator', blank=True, null=True)` to User, and in my case, run a bunch of `l.user_set.add(u)` calls to create the associations for data I already have. I think the `blank=True, null=True` was part of my hang up - how to make the relationship optional. Thanks, Brian and lanzz.